# Check for mxd write access with python addin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-addin, mxd

I'm looking for a way to check for writing access to an mxd upon the initiation of a python AddIn tool. My tool should only be enabled if the user has writing access to the mxd. I thought there was a way to check for read/write access using `arcpy` (or maybe `os`?) but it's lost on me now. I tried the following as a work-around (saving upon initiation):

```
class ToolClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
        try: mxd.save ()
        except IOError:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox ("The map document is locked.",
                                     "Map file locked", 0)
            self.enabled = False
```

However, this doesn't produce an `IOError`. Instead I get a warning box (below) from ArcMap and the `try` is successful and the `except` is ignored.

[image]

I've also tried making use of `os.access`, but without results (`os.access (mapPath, os.W_OK)` returns `True`):

```
mapPath = mxd.filePath
if not os.access (mapPath, os.W_OK):
    pythonaddins.MessageBox ("The map document is locked.",
                             "Map file locked", 0)
    self.enabled = False
```

---

I've now realized that I was thinking of `arcpy.TestSchemaLock`, but according to the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/analyze/arcpy-functions/testschemalock.htm) this is only for feature classes, tables, and feature datasets.

Developing with version 10.4 but the end users will be 10.1.

Comment: Just going to ask the obvious here, you have sufficient space on your hard drive? Also, we've had issues like this in a Citrix environment where the file server wasn't synchronizing with what we were seeing.

Comment: I am almost sure you would need to use `win32security` from `pywin32`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896638/checking-folder-file-ntfs-permissions-using-python

Comment: Just try to open it for write access and catch the IO exception and do something else, pass, timer, whatever.  open( filepath, 'w' )

Comment: @geodranic this method produces the IOError regardless of the current ArcMap's session write access. I can try this method and get the error while still able to execute `mxd.save ()`.

Comment: What technique did you use to restrict access? Is this file on a network drive that a user can't edit, is it a read-only permission on the file itself? Is the user part of a particular security group? I'm not sure the answer changes depending on how you've restricted that file, but it might be useful to know.

Comment: Following your saving upon initialization workaround, maybe you could check the timestamp with `mxd.dateSaved()` before attempting to save. Then check it again after and compare. If it hasn't changed then `mxd.save()` failed